# Is The GSUB Table Widely Populated In TrueType Fonts?

Tags: fonts, truetype, text-rendering, opentype, harfbuzz

Long story short, I'm rendering font without the use of FreeType or HarfBuzz (for various reasons), by manually parsing TrueType and derivative formats to extract metadata and glyph information, to later build bitmaps and distance fields from their outlines at runtime. Something I'm concerned about is reliable glyph substitution where essential, i.e. where certain sequences must be replaced as per the language rules, by another.

What I'm unclear about is how reliable the GSUB table can generally be assumed to be. In other words, is it reasonable to expect that an Arabic font, for example, should provide a populated GSUB table containing the substitutions required for an Arabic script? Or, given that this is per-script, is it generally assumed that fonts would only provide special, per-font substitutions, while the shaping engine is assumed to handle any per-script substituions as global rules? I'm not concerned that the substituted glyph(s) may be unavailable, as the system searches for fallbacks in that case, else reverts to the original sequence.

Obviously having a global ruleset in place per-script would be totally reliable as a fallback, but I want to keep this as minimal as possible. Apologies that this isn't exactly an empirical question, but I'm having trouble finding much information on this, short of having to actually examine a large sample of various fonts. [This overview](http://pfaedit.sourceforge.net/gposgsub.html) seems to suggest that per-script substitutions will be defined, but given that the tables are modular, there is of course no guarantee that there will even be a table, let alone the required definitions. Failing this, is there any known database of substitutions for various scripts?

Comment: GSUB tables move *glyphs* around (you don't mention it, but these are not Unicode codepoints), and so they can only work with the actual glyphs *in that same font*. The whole design concept of OpenType features is that they are defined by that font, and exclusively *for* that font. There cannot be a GSUB rule that replaces a glyph with one not in the font. It would indicate an invalid font instead.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thank you, that really helped clear a few things up. I had read the spec, especially around ScriptList data, but this worry mostly came from not knowing what goes into actually designing and producing a font. I found it surprising that each font would have to supply what are essentially duplicate rules in a lot of cases, so it's welcome that I don't need to deal with any such global rules myself.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: sorry :) I meant "moves glyphs around" in a metaphysical way – only inside the font is what I meant. Indeed GSUB only *replaces* glyphs, and GPOS more physically *moves* them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modern OpenType font file is effectively a fully self-contained typesetting program, and a text shaper only gets to "do as instructed by the font" (even if that requires a whole bunch of complexity on the shaper's part), and so there are prebaked list of GSUB rules that are bundled with shapers that are consulted outside of what the font specifies.

Think of the font as a game rom: while you need a good emulator (text shaper) to properly run the game (font), and it's the emulator's job to make sure all the complex bits like blitting, memory swapping, etc. gets performed at the right time, the *game* specifies what will happen. Similary, a good text shaper will have all the (complex) logic for how to interpret the OpenType data, and how to process it, in which order, over how many passes, etc. but that data comes *only* from the font, and nowhere else.

Of course, that doesn't mean that those kind of lists don't exist: they just don't exist *in shapers*. They absolutely exist in font building tools, because the job of designing typefaces would be incredibly tedious without them, but each tool has their own lists and presets, and when they generate a font all those rules are encoded into the font file itself: the font becomes the source of truth when it comes to typesetting.

If you have a font file, you have all the information needed to shape text, provided your shaper code parses the font in compliance with the OpenType specification, and part of that compliance is that the shaper is only allowed to apply what's in the font.

(Of course, there is some configurability in that OpenType features are explicitly designed in a way that a shaper is allowed to *skip* applying any or all of them, but it is not allowed to *add* any of its own)

Comment: Comments above that GSUB provides glyph substitutions and that substitutions can only be done to glyph in the same font — those comments are correct. However, other key aspects in the comments and in this answer are not correct. Please see the answer I've provided.

Answer (score 3):

It's not accurate to say that an OpenType font is a fully self-contained typesetting program, and that a "text shaper only gets to 'do as instructed by the font'". Especially for scripts like Arabic or Devanagari, there is very essential logic common across fonts that is implemented in the text shaper.

The implication is that supporting something like Arabic is not at all as simple a matter as implementing logic to parse the 'GSUB' and 'GPOS' tables and apply lookups (actions) within. This is definitely not a small undertaking, and I would certainly look for existing implementations to re-use.

You mention that you have chosen not to use Harfbuzz. I recommend you reconsider that.

> What I'm unclear about is how reliable the GSUB table can generally be assumed to be. In other words, is it reasonable to expect that an Arabic font, for example, should provide a populated GSUB table containing the substitutions required for an Arabic script?

Absolutely! An Arabic font must have 'GSUB', 'GPOS' and 'GDEF' tables in order to display Arabic text correctly. Per-script / cross-font substitutions are not possible, in principle let alone in practice.

Some resources you might find useful—some are old (the MS Typography site was republished so dates are pages don't always reflect the original publication date), but the content is still relevant. And while Windows may be referenced, it applies to any OpenType layout engine.

- [Windows glyph processing for OpenType fonts, part 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/processing-part1]
- [Windows glyph processing for OpenType fonts, part 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/processing-part2)
- [OpenType Spec, Advanced Typographic Extensions - OpenType Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/ttochap1)

  - **Note:** This (unfortunately) doesn't call out the essential role of shaping engines.
- [Developing OpenType Fonts for Arabic Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/script-development/arabic)

  - This is one script-specific topic, related to Arabic. Note in particular the discussion of what an Arabic shaping engine needs to do.

Comment: When I say fully self contained I'm talking about the same kind of fully self contained as a game ROM is: of course the interpreter (font shaper, console hardware emulator, etc) has to do a lot of complicated work but _all_ of them effectively have to do that in the same way (not even in code, but in result) if we want to call them "proper" shapers/emulators/etc. Naturally, there's a lot of code in the shaper that _applies_ the font's features, but it doesn't get to add in its own GSUB rules (plus, how would it? glyph ids aren't even consistent between different generations of the same font)

Comment: GSUB lookups define substitution actions using font-specific glyph IDs, and a shaping implementation can generate other glyph substitutions because it has no font-specific knowledge. If that's what you're meaning, then that's correct.

Comment: However, reading your comments in reply to Josh's question seemed to me to suggest that all a rendering implementation needs to do is to parse the lookup tables in the font and perform the substitutions indicated, and that is not correct: the rendering engine needs to do cluster analysis, re-ordering of glyphs within a cluster, apply certain features to particular sub-ranges, then process the lookups triggered by features. And the way all that needs to be.done may be different from one script to another. It's important for Josh to understand that if he wants to implement his own renderer.

Comment: "a fully self-contained typesetting program" would be more appropriately applied to Apple's AAT and SIL's Graphite font data. Both of these use a single, truly-generic runtime and all of the shaping logic is fully self-contained within the font itself. But neither is nearly as widely supported in software or in font-development tools as is OpenType.

Comment: good point, I forgot to delete those comments after writing the answer. I guess the main problem is that it sounds like you think of a "program" as something different from what I thin of, so I should probably make that more nuanced. To me, the software that gets interpreted is already the "full program", with the additional logic that comes from the interpreter (python/js interpreter, text shaper, emulator, etc) simply being a given to _run_ that program. It'll be complex as heck, but that complexity is merely there to properly execute the program (in line will the specs and conventions).